# How can I make a live thread (vidiprinter) type section of my site?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make a section of my site like a vidiprinter stlye thing where I can update it and the page will refresh automatically on the user's device without them having to refresh. Ideally if I could allow other people who I specify to update the thread as well that would be great but is not essential. Is there any way that I can do this? (As simple as possible)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have javascript check / make an ajax call to some back end page to check for updated. I'd also save the time stamp of the last time the page was updated, and then check if the newest comment / update time stamp is greater than the old time stamp, then update the page either by refreshing the whole page, or by adding the info right there from an an ajax call.